# HashMap not counting duplicate characters

Tags: java, count, hashmap, character

My question is why cant i get HASHMAP to count duplicate characters from multiple lines, instead it outputs character count per word, see text example:

Where do we go from here

Down town city i guess

at twelve noon

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class DupChar{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    try
    {
    File f = new File("C:/JavaPrograms/text.txt");
    Scanner s = new Scanner(f);
    while (s.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = s.next();
        String lineArr = line.replaceAll("\t", "");
        HashMap<Character, Integer> charMap = new HashMap<Character,  Integer>();
        char[] arr = lineArr.toCharArray();
        for (char value: arr) {
            if (Character.isAlphabetic(value)) {  
                if (charMap.containsKey(value)) {
                    charMap.put(value, charMap.get(value) + 1);
                } else {
                    charMap.put(value, 1);
                    }
            }
        }
    System.out.println(charMap);
    }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }    
}
```

my output was, not what i wanted:

{e=1, H=1}

{r=1, e=2, w=1, h=1}

{d=1, o=1}

{e=1, w=1}

etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
String line = s.next();
```

into

```
String line = s.nextLine();
```

---

Other possibilities:

```
        Map<Character, Integer> charMap = new HashMap<>();
```

And for

```
                if (charMap.containsKey(value)) {
                    charMap.put(value, charMap.get(value) + 1);
                } else {
                    charMap.put(value, 1);
                }
```

simply

```
                //charMap.merge(value, 1, (oldv, newv) -> oldv + 1);
                charMap.merge(value, 1, Integer::sum);
```

---

***The five most frequent entries***

Let's use the java Stream; as that is trendy "query language" for collections.

```
charMap.entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry<Character, Integer>::getValue).reversed())
    .limit(5)
    .forEach(entry -> System.out.printf("'%c' : %d%n", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
```

The above is sorted on decreasing frequency.

Unfortunately for characters having the same frequency this becomes more elaborate.

Sorted on letter would be:

```
charMap.entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry<Character, Integer>::getValue).reversed())
    .limit(5)
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry<Character, Integer>::getKey))
    .forEach(entry -> System.out.printf("'%c' : %d%n", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
```

Taking the 2 highest frequencies, and presenting *all* characters having those frequencies:

```
import java.util.Map.Entry;

            charMap.entrySet().stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Entry<Character, Integer>::getValue))
                    .entrySet()
                    .stream()
                    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(
                        Entry<Integer, List<Entry<Character, Integer>>>::getKey)
                        .reversed())
                    .limit(2) // To highest frequencies
                    .map(e -> e.getValue())
                    .flatMap(List<Entry<Character, Integer>>::stream)
                    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Entry<Character, Integer>::getKey))
                    .forEach(entry -> System.out.printf("# '%c' : %d%n",
                                      entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
```

This already becomes hard to read.

Comment: Again thanks a lot. The first issue with code posted for correction is not sorted yet. I think i reacted too quickly before. Looking through my output; its not yet fixed e.g. still have one character counted in two or more places. Please look at code again; will be waiting.

Comment: I gave sorted on decreasing frequency. Added some variants. I hope it gives a taste of java Streams.

Answer (score 0):

HashMap don't hold duplicate value instead if overwrite value of that key

Comment: Kushavaha do you mean hashSet()